# Weird scroll behavior with fixed size container of a changing img

Tags: html, css

I have a page with 100% height and width, img container with fixed size and an img that changes every second. Img is centered vertically and horizontally inside its container.

The problem is that when you scroll down half a cat, scroll starts jumping up and down when img changes.

Can someone explain this behavior?
I have a [codepen](https://codepen.io/astupak/pen/ExaKGJW) illustrating the issue.

html:

```html
<div class="to-change-container">
  <img class="to-change"></img>
</div>
<div class="height-stratcher"></div>
```

css:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  overflow: auto;
}

.to-change-container {
  height: 300px;
  width:300px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.height-stratcher {
  height: 1000px;
}

.to-change {
  max-height: 100%;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

js:

```js
picLinks = [
  'https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/43cdd26dcc65986fac314bcab0d4d2be.jpg',
  'https://pngriver.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/04/Download-Red-Cat-PNG.png',
  'https://www.meme-arsenal.com/memes/d5054013f48d02a72a054bae89a15992.jpg'
]

setInterval(()=> {
  let element = document.getElementsByClassName('to-change')[0];

  element.src = picLinks[Math.floor(Math.random()*10) % 3];
}, 1000);
```

**UPD**

Setting `overflow: hidden` seems to fix the issue shown in the original codepen. Adding changing text before the image [breaks it again](https://codepen.io/astupak/pen/dyPXOra).

Also image does not seem to affect image container dimensions.

Is there a way to fit image into container without cropping and stratching it?

Comment: I can't reproduce this issue with your codepen. Neither in chrome, nor in Edge. Can you clarify what exactly happens or maybe post a gif?

Comment: Pay attention to the scrollbar on the right [gif](https://imgur.com/a/uNOAMc4).

You need to scroll down a little first to see the scrollbar jumping.

Answer (score 1):

limco is correct

```
.to-change-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Will solve your problems.

The issue is with flex box and the fact the the images from the API are all different sizes and are expanding the containing div. Display flex doesn't behave like display block sizes can vary when the children change.

If you are worried about cropping with overflow hidden you could always choose to set the to-change-container to display:block and set the image inside to 100% width and auto height, there are a few different strategies you could use.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It did fix the scrollbar jumping in a codepen.

But I checked image container size without `overflow: hidden`, it does not change. So I don't think image sizes affect the image container.
I made another [codepen](https://codepen.io/astupak/pen/dyPXOra) with an image label on top of an image, image container has overflow hidden and scrollbar is still jumping all over the place. Can you check it out?

Comment: If you put 'border: solid 1px red' on the container and 'border: solid 1px blue' on the image you'll see what I mean, you can see the height of the container bounce around at the bottom when the image changes.

Comment: That's because scrollbar is jumping. Scroll all the way to the top so the whole container is in view, dimensions don't change.

Answer (score 0):

You need to make your image responsive and you can achieve it with this styles:

```
.to-change-container img {
    display: inline-block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

Comment: please give context to your answer so that it is relevant to the asked question

Answer (score 0):

The big cat face image is bigger than the others and seems to be affecting the height.

Try this:

```
.to-change-container {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The scroll bar jumps due to the images being different in their height.
If you want to keep the scroll bar, you need set a fixed height for the images. Try this:

```css
.to-change-container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.to-change {
  height: 300px;
  width: auto;
}
```

Otherwise, set `overflow: hidden;` as the other answers pointed out.

Comment: Images are different in height, but I can't see image container dimensions changing in devtools. I did another [codepen](https://codepen.io/astupak/pen/dyPXOra) with container's overflow hidden. Same issue. Changing align-items to start (or anything else that's not `center`) seems to fix it, but picture is not centered.

Comment: You need to set it on the body element: `body {
  overflow: hidden;
}`. However, this will hide scroll bars for the whole page.

Comment: Otherwise try to give your container a fixed height that is higher than the height of your image with the greatest height (did this make sense lol?)

Comment: It destroys the idea of a different sized pictures in a fixed size container :)